# How to sum total the attendance of various age groups in third section of tableview using swift instead of implementing new controller?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Here is the picture of what has been implemented till now.

[image]

**Aim:** To show the total of the the attendance of the age group in the third section in table view.

**What we applied**: Tried applying the label with new variable that can count the cell of the increase and decrease button function.

**What is the issue:** The increase and decrease button click still gets repeated in the third section of the tableview where we want only label to show the total of the attendance of the age group

**What we Tried**:
1.Tried applying the label with new variable that can count the cell of the increase and decrease button function, unfortunately the app crashes if ["0"] is used for new variable to implement total sum.  --> var itemValue2 = ["0"]
2.Tried to implement using new controller but same thing happens.

Below is the code of the class AdditionalGuestInformationVC::

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC
import SSSpinnerButton

class AdditionalGuestInforTVCell: UITableViewCell {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDetails: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var btnMinus: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var lblValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnPlus: UIButton!
}

class AdditionalGuestInformationVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let section = ["Male", "Female", "total"]

    let itemsName = [["Shishu", "Baal", "Kishore", "Tarun", "Yuva", "Jyeshta"], ["Shishu", "Baalika", "Kishori", "Taruni", "Yuvati", "Jyeshtaa"], ["Total:"]]
    let itemsDetails = [["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"], ["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"],["Attendees"]]
    var itemValue = [["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"], ["0"]]
   
    
    var dicMember = [[String:Any]]()
    
    var strDate = ""
    var utsavName = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var lblShakhaName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblDate: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var btnSubmit: SSSpinnerButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.fillData()

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationBarDesign(txt_title: "guest_information".localized, showbtn: "back")
        self.firebaseAnalytics(_eventName: "AdditionalGuestInfoVC")
    }
    
    
    func fillData() {
        self.lblDate.text = strDate
    }
    
    @objc func onMinusClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let sectionIndex = ((sender.tag / 10) - 10)
        let rowIndex = (sender.tag % 10)

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? AdditionalGuestInforTVCell
        
        var strVal : Int = Int((cell?.lblValue.text)!)!

        if strVal > 0 {
            strVal -= 1
        }
        self.itemValue[sectionIndex][rowIndex] = "\(Int(strVal))"
        tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath as IndexPath], with:.automatic)

    }
    
    @objc func onPlusClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let sectionIndex = ((sender.tag / 10) - 10)
        let rowIndex = (sender.tag % 10)

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? AdditionalGuestInforTVCell
        
        var strVal : Int = Int((cell?.lblValue.text)!)!

        if strVal < 99 {
            strVal += 1
        }
        self.itemValue[sectionIndex][rowIndex] = "\(Int(strVal))"
        tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath as IndexPath], with:.automatic)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onPreviewClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AttendancePreviewVC") as! AttendancePreviewVC
        vc.itemsName = self.itemsName
        vc.itemsDetails = self.itemsDetails
        vc.itemValue = self.itemValue
        vc.dicMember = self.dicMember
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onSubmitClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        btnSubmit.startAnimate(spinnerType: SpinnerType.circleStrokeSpin, spinnercolor: .white, spinnerSize: 20, complete: {
            // Your code here
            self.addSankhyaAPI()
            let disableMyButton = sender as? UIButton
            disableMyButton?.isEnabled = false
        })
    }
    
    // MARK: TableView Methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self.section[section]
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return self.section.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width - 40, height: 60)
        let footerView = UIView(frame:rect)
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 229.0/255.0, green: 229.0/255.0, blue: 229.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: footerView.center.y / 2, width: 160, height: 30))
        lblTitle.text = "Guest Information"
        lblTitle.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 20.0)
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        lblTitle.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 154.0/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 154.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let lblGender = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30.0 + lblTitle.frame.width, y: footerView.center.y / 2, width: 80, height: 30))
        lblGender.text = self.section[section]
        lblGender.font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-SemiBold", size: 16.0)
        lblGender.textColor = UIColor.black
        lblGender.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 230.0/255.0, blue: 190.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        lblGender.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        lblGender.layer.masksToBounds = true
        lblGender.textAlignment = .center
        
        footerView.addSubview(lblGender)
        footerView.addSubview(lblTitle)
        return footerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60  // or whatever
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.itemsName[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdditionalGuestInforTVCell", for: indexPath) as! AdditionalGuestInforTVCell

        cell.lblName.text = self.itemsName[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.lblDetails.text = self.itemsDetails[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.lblValue.text = self.itemValue[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.btnMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onMinusClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.btnPlus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPlusClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let strSection : String = "\(indexPath.section + 10)"
        let strRow = "\(indexPath.row)"
        
        cell.btnPlus.tag = Int(strSection + strRow)!
        cell.btnMinus.tag = Int(strSection + strRow)!
        cell.lblValue.tag = Int(strSection + strRow)!
  

        return cell
    }


    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension //Choose your custom row height
    }

    
    func addSankhyaAPI() {
        
        let arrFilter : [String] = self.dicMember.filter { $0["isPresent"] as! String == "true" }.map { $0["member_id"]! as! String }
        let stringArr = arrFilter.joined(separator: " ")
        let stringArray = stringArr.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ", ", options: .literal, range: nil)

        
        var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
        parameters["user_id"] = _appDelegator.dicMemberProfile![0]["user_id"] as? String // dicUserDetails["user_id"]
        parameters["event_date"] = strDate
        parameters["org_chapter_id"] = _appDelegator.dicMemberProfile![0]["shakha_id"]
        parameters["utsav"] = utsavName
        parameters["member_id"] = stringArray
        parameters["shishu_male"] = self.itemValue[0][0]
        parameters["baal"] = self.itemValue[0][1]
        parameters["kishore"] = self.itemValue[0][2]
        parameters["tarun"] = self.itemValue[0][3]
        parameters["yuva"] = self.itemValue[0][4]
        parameters["proudh"] = self.itemValue[0][5]
        parameters["shishu_female"] = self.itemValue[1][0]
        parameters["baalika"] = self.itemValue[1][1]
        parameters["kishori"] = self.itemValue[1][2]
        parameters["taruni"] = self.itemValue[1][3]
        parameters["yuvati"] = self.itemValue[1][4]
        parameters["proudha"] = self.itemValue[1][5]
        parameters["total:"] = self.itemValue[2]
        parameters["api"] = "yes"
        
        print(parameters)
        
        APIManager.sharedInstance.callPostApi(url: APIUrl.add_sankhya, parameters: parameters) { (jsonData, error) in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let status = jsonData!["status"].int
                {
                    if status == 1
                    {
                        self.btnSubmit.stopAnimationWithCompletionTypeAndBackToDefaults(completionType: .success, backToDefaults: true, complete: {
                            // Your code here
                            if let strMessage = jsonData!["message"].string {
                                showAlert(title: APP.title, message: strMessage)
                            }
                        })
                    }else {
                        self.btnSubmit.stopAnimationWithCompletionTypeAndBackToDefaults(completionType: .fail, backToDefaults: true, complete: {
                            // Your code here
                            if let strError = jsonData!["message"].string {
                                showAlert(title: APP.title, message: strError)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    self.btnSubmit.stopAnimationWithCompletionTypeAndBackToDefaults(completionType: .fail, backToDefaults: true, complete: {
                        // Your code here
                        if let strError = jsonData!["message"].string {
                            showAlert(title: APP.title, message: strError)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic but I think you should learn how to separate your data models and business logic from your view controller into different types. It will help in situations like this.

Comment: thank you. i'll keep that in mind and improve on the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the code with three functions:: To show it like below image:[image: Solution image][image: Footer]

```
@objc func onMinusClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let section = (sender.tag / 10) - 10
    let row = sender.tag % 10
    var value = Int(self.itemValue[section][row]) ?? 0
    value -= 1
    if value < 0 {
        value = 0
    }
    self.itemValue[section][row] = "\(value)"
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AdditionalGuestInforTVCell {
        cell.lblValue.text = self.itemValue[section][row]
    }
    calculateTotal()
}

@objc func onPlusClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let section = (sender.tag / 10) - 10
    let row = sender.tag % 10
    var value = Int(self.itemValue[section][row]) ?? 0
    value += 1
    self.itemValue[section][row] = "\(value)"
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AdditionalGuestInforTVCell {
        cell.lblValue.text = self.itemValue[section][row]
    }
    calculateTotal()
}



func calculateTotal() {
    var total = 0
    for i in 0..<itemValue.count {
        for j in 0..<itemValue[i].count {
            total += Int(itemValue[i][j]) ?? 0
        }
    }
  
    
    let totalMembers = dicMember.count

    let totalMembersLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 80))
    totalMembersLabel.text = "Sankhya: \(totalMembers)\nGuest Sankhya: \(total) \nTotal Sankhya: \(totalMembers + total)"
    totalMembersLabel.numberOfLines = 5
    totalMembersLabel.textAlignment = .center
    totalMembersLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = totalMembersLabel
    
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 80))
    label.text = " Guest Sankhya: \(total)"
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    tableView.tableFooterView = label
    
    let combinedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 80))
    combinedLabel.text = "Guest Sankhya: \(total) "

    combinedLabel.textAlignment = .center
    combinedLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    tableView.tableFooterView = combinedLabel
}
```

call  calculateTotal() inside tableView for viewForHeaderInSection

```
//existing code
calculateTotal()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to move your button actions **inside** your `AdditionalGuestInforTVCell`  cell class, then use a `closure` to tell the controller that the value changed.

Use a second `UITableViewCell` class as your "Total" cell - with two labels, so it looks like this:

[image]

When your `AdditionalGuestInforTVCell`  cell tells the controller its value changed, update your data, get the sum of all the "items" and reload the 3rd section.

Here's a quick example...

First, let's use a `struct` to define your data:

```
struct ItemStruct {
    var itemName: String = ""
    var itemDetails: String = ""
    var itemCount: Int = 0
}
```

In your controller, we'll use a var property like this:

```
// our data is now an Array of ItemStruct Arrays
//  so we'll have one Array per section
var myData: [[ItemStruct]] = []
```

and we'll initialize the data like this...

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // all the normal view setup

    myData = getData()
}

func getData() -> [[ItemStruct]] {
    let itemsName = [
        ["Shishu", "Baal", "Kishore", "Tarun", "Yuva", "Jyeshta"],
        ["Shishu", "Baalika", "Kishori", "Taruni", "Yuvati", "Jyeshtaa"],
    ]
    let itemsDetails = [
        ["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"],
        ["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"],
    ]
    
    var tmpArray: [[ItemStruct]] = []
    
    // let's fill our data with names and details
    for (names, details) in zip(itemsName, itemsDetails) {
        var secData: [ItemStruct] = []
        for i in 0..<names.count {
            let d = ItemStruct(itemName: names[i], itemDetails: details[i], itemCount: 0)
            secData.append(d)
        }
        tmpArray.append(secData)
    }
    
    return tmpArray

}
```

---

Here's a complete, runnable example. We create everything via code - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections - so all you need to do is assign the custom class of a plain `UIViewController` as `AdditionalGuestInformationVC`. I've tried to include enough in-line comments in the code to make things clear:

```
struct ItemStruct {
    var itemName: String = ""
    var itemDetails: String = ""
    var itemCount: Int = 0
}


class TotalCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var lblTitle = UILabel()
    var lblValue = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // label properties
        lblTitle.text = "Total Attendees:"
        lblValue.textAlignment = .center
        
        // add views to contentView
        [lblTitle, lblValue].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // use content view's defaualt margins
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // this avoids autolayout complaints
        let c = lblTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // Name label Top / Leading
            lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            lblTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            c,
            
            // Value label Trailing
            lblValue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            lblValue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            // vertically center Value label
            lblValue.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    func fillData(_ value: Int) {
        lblValue.text = "\(value)"
    }
    
}

class AdditionalGuestInforTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    // closure to inform the controller that the count changed
    var countChanged: ((UITableViewCell, Int) -> ())?
    
    var lblName = UILabel()
    var lblDetails = UILabel()
    
    var btnMinus = UIButton()
    var lblValue = UILabel()
    var btnPlus = UIButton()
    
    // we'll automatically update the value label when the count changes
    var currentItemCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            lblValue.text = "\(currentItemCount)"
        }
    }
    
    @objc func minusTap() {
        if currentItemCount > 0 {
            // decrement current count
            currentItemCount -= 1
            
            // inform the controller
            countChanged?(self, currentItemCount)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func plusTap() {
        // increment current count
        currentItemCount += 1
        
        // inform the controller
        countChanged?(self, currentItemCount)
    }
    
    // we'll fill the labels from our data struct object
    func fillData(_ data: ItemStruct) {
        lblName.text = "\(data.itemName)"
        lblDetails.text = "\(data.itemDetails)"
        self.currentItemCount = data.itemCount
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // label properties
        lblDetails.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        lblDetails.textColor = .gray
        lblDetails.numberOfLines = 0
        
        lblValue.textAlignment = .center
        
        // button titles
        btnMinus.setTitle("-", for: [])
        btnPlus.setTitle("+", for: [])
        
        // button style
        [btnMinus, btnPlus].forEach { b in
            b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            b.layer.borderWidth = 1
            b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        }
        
        // add views to contentView
        [lblName, lblDetails, btnMinus, lblValue, btnPlus].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // use content view's defaualt margins
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // this avoids autolayout complaints
        let c = lblDetails.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // Name label Top / Leading
            lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            lblName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // Details label Top (to Name label Bottom) / Leading / Bottom
            lblDetails.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblName.bottomAnchor, constant: 6.0),
            lblDetails.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            c,

            // plus button Trailing
            btnPlus.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // Value label Trailing (to Plus button Leading)
            lblValue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnPlus.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // Minus button Trailing (to Value label Leading)
            btnMinus.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblValue.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // buttons and Value label centered vertically
            btnPlus.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            lblValue.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            btnMinus.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            btnMinus.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            btnPlus.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnMinus.widthAnchor),
            lblValue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnMinus.widthAnchor),

            // Details label Trailing ("right edge")
            lblDetails.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnMinus.leadingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])

        btnMinus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(minusTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnPlus.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusTap), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
    
}

class AdditionalGuestInformationVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    let section = ["Male", "Female", "Total"]
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var myData: [[ItemStruct]] = []

    func getData() -> [[ItemStruct]] {
        let itemsName = [
            ["Shishu", "Baal", "Kishore", "Tarun", "Yuva", "Jyeshta"],
            ["Shishu", "Baalika", "Kishori", "Taruni", "Yuvati", "Jyeshtaa"],
        ]
        let itemsDetails = [
            ["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"],
            ["Below 5 Years - Pre-primary ", "5 to 11 Years - Primary School", "11 to 16 Years - Middle School", "17 to 25 Years - High School/College", "25 to 60 Years - Adults", ">60 Years - Senior citizen"],
        ]
        
        var tmpArray: [[ItemStruct]] = []
        
        // let's fill our data with names and details
        for (names, details) in zip(itemsName, itemsDetails) {
            var secData: [ItemStruct] = []
            for i in 0..<names.count {
                let d = ItemStruct(itemName: names[i], itemDetails: details[i], itemCount: 0)
                secData.append(d)
            }
            tmpArray.append(secData)
        }
        
        return tmpArray

    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // Top / Leading / Trailing inset by 20-points (so we can see the table frame)
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // let's leave some space at the bottom
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -80.0),
            
        ])
        
        // register the "input" cells
        tableView.register(AdditionalGuestInforTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AdditionalGuestInforTVCell")
        // register the "Total" cell
        tableView.register(TotalCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "totalCell")
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        myData = getData()
        
    }

    // MARK: TableView Methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.section[section]
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // add 1 for the Total section
        return myData.count + 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // if it's the last section, it's the Total section
        if section == myData.count {
            return 1
        }
        return myData[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // if it's the last section, it's the Total section
        if indexPath.section == myData.count {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "totalCell", for: indexPath) as! TotalCell
            
            // get the total of values from all data
            var total: Int = 0
            for i in 0..<self.myData.count {
                total += self.myData[i].reduce(0) { $0 + $1.itemCount }
            }
            
            cell.fillData(total)
            
            return cell
        }
        
        // it's not the last section
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdditionalGuestInforTVCell", for: indexPath) as! AdditionalGuestInforTVCell
        cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
        
        // add closure
        cell.countChanged = { [weak self] aCell, aValue in
            guard let self = self,
                  let thisCell = aCell as? AdditionalGuestInforTVCell,
                  let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: thisCell)
            else { return }
            
            // update the data
            self.myData[idxPath.section][idxPath.row].itemCount = aValue
            
            // reload the last section (the "Total" section)
            self.tableView.reloadSections([self.myData.count], with: .none)
            
        }
        return cell

    }
    
}
```

and it should look like this when running:

[image] [image]

Comment: it doesn't navigate to this view and gives error of key value pair for btnsubmit outlet. (BTW im using storyboard and not SwiftUI)

Comment: @Jigardave - this was meant to be ***instructional***. If you create a new project and assign the default controller in Storyboard to `AdditionalGuestInformationVC` you can run this directly to see it working. Then, go through the code and ***learn*** what it's doing -- and implement it in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works exactly as you have showed in the answer by creating in individual project. Nevertheless, as there are two API called to "post" the number of attendees from "AdditionalGuestInformationVC" while "get" the number of attendees in SankhyaVC. It becomes very complex to exactly fetch the details. It would be very much helpful if you could add some details to what i should change in or how can i implement  'func addSankhyaAPI()' as it is the post method via submit button to add the attendees

Comment: @Jigardave - how to get/post data with an API is a very different. Best to post that as a new question.

Comment: i have created the question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373598/how-to-calculate-and-show-the-total-number-of-attendees-from-two-different-views

Comment: @Jigardave - did you thoroughly go through that sample code, so you understand how the increment/decrement buttons in the cells are communicating with the controller? If so, you really should have no problem editing ***your existing code*** to implement that functionality.